# How to automate workflow in git?

Tags: linux, git, bash, unix

Now I do this:

```
git commit -a -m "comment"
```

then (to bitbucket.org)

```
git push
```

then (to hosting via ftp)

```
git ftp push
```

I want to run these commands automatically:

```
git fix "comment"
```

or so:

```
gitfix "comment"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a bash function:

```
gitfix() {
  git commit -a -m "$1" && git push && git ftp push
}
```

and put it in your `~/.bashrc` file so you can just execute it from the terminal as `gitfix "some commit comment"`

**Update**: Concatenated the commands with &&, so, in case of failure, the remaining commands will not be executed. Thanks to **burper** for this update.

Comment: I suggest to concatenate the commands with `&&`, so, in case of failure, the remaining commands will not be executed.

Comment: Yes that's a nice improvement, I've added it to the answer, thank you.